# Hyperledger Explorer showing only 1 node for 7 peers under 1 organization configured in hyperledger fabric. Is it correct?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-explorer

[Hyperledger explorer showing 1 node for 7 peers configured under 1 organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omUIt.jpg)

A single organization is created called ORG1MSP. 7 peers are configured under same organization starting from peer0.org1.example.com through peer6.org1.example.com. All transactions running fine. 
To visualize the fabric network I setup an Hyperledger Explorer which shows up **only 1 node as against expected 7 nodes.** I am expected to setup 7 nodes to be setup under single organization. What am i missing on?

Comment: It seems that all pers are running on the same machine\VM

Comment: Yes Bassel absolutely!! So it is fine right?

Comment: Yes, it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bassel is right here.

Shashank, I think you have done a fantastic job so far.

want to give a little perspective here. The idea of decentralized systems is to have multiple nodes for its known benefits. I would motivate you to do that with your app too. Deploy it to multiple nodes.

1. Then visualize it on explorer. Get a sense of pride. At this stage u earned it my friend.
2. Kill one node ( mock the DDoS scenario) and see if your network is still stable.
3. Run transactions and Monitor the speed as compared to single node ( single VM as mentioned above in the comments)
4. You just graduated to develop de-cen systems of which blockchain is a part ( if fabric is your first attempt at de-cen systems, I would assume in this case).

Good luck

Comment: Hey Vikas, nice to see your thoughts man! It would be great if you share any blog/posts links here which can guide us through setting up network on multiple nodes for fabric using docker swarm

Comment: Glad you liked it . Sure. I will do that soon and post it here. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks again. I think you are doing hyperledger for some time now. I've been only doing it since last 3 weeks. Meanwhile share some resource links here on that so I could give it a try as well. The hyperledgers would be impressed and thankful if you do it all alone and post here!

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed 2 peers now on 2 separate virtual machines using docker swarm networking.
On first virtual machine, we have ca, orderer, peer0 and couchdb0 running. On second virtual machine we have peer1 and couchdb1 running. 
The business network is installed on the fabric using hyperledger composer. Still the blockchain explorer is showing nodes as 1 against expectation of 2 nodes.

[Blockchain explorer showing just 1 node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEZmp.jpg)